# How to display a "Standby" screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I'm looking for a way to display a "stand-by screen" for within my app.

I have a main activity with a fragment and I've added a button to the side of the main activity to trigger when this "Stand-by" screen should show, which will be nothing more than displaying a picture.

I have already **tried changing the content view**, it works for setting the screen but when I try set it back to activity_main it throws an error about being unable to inflate the fragment.

Which lead me to try **creating a linearlayout view programmatically** (spelling?) and setting this view visible with setvisibility but this doesn't work either.

I have also looked at **AlertDialog** but I don't think this is the best way to do this.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest? add an `ImageView` or any `View` with opaque background as the last element of your layout, with dimensions `MATCH_PARENT` / `MATCH_PARENT` and Visibility `GONE`.

When you want to show it, just call `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` , or `view.setVisiblity(View.GONE)` to hide it. It will come up above the rest of elements, which will be hidden under its opaque background.

```
View view=findViewById(R.id.yourSplashId);
```

show

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

hide

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I see in your question that you tried this approach and it didn't work. Maybe that View you generated was behind the fragment?

You can also put your Fragment + splash inside a ViewFlipper

```
<ViewFlipper>
     <fragment>...</fragment>
     <FrameLayout>
         <imageView>
         <progressbar> .. etc
     </FrameLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

this has the added benefit that you can setup animations for transitions etc.. In this case:

```
ViewFlipper myFlipper=findViewById(R.id.myFlipper);
myFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0); // fragment
myFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);  // splash
```

and

```
myFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.left_in));
myFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.right_out));
```

Comment: I'll give it a try now thank you, looks like what I was attempting to do but done right haha

Comment: Well..it does work but it pushes all buttons/controls etc off screen after it's set invisible again

Comment: it shouldnt if its visibility is "GONE" instead of "INVISIBLE". post your XML so I can take a look

Comment: Ah you're right, that is pretty much what I wanted to do thank you, I'll accept this as correct but I'm also going to look into the viewflipper now as the transition animations would be nice thank you!